# Проблема с списком enemys

Tags: python, pygame

у меня есть список enemys в котором `enemys[0][0]` это `enemys_x`, а `enemys[0][1]` - `enemy_y` список выглядит так:

```py
[[enemy_x, enemy_y, enemy_size, enemy_size, color]]
```

полная ошибка:

```
line 40, in painter
    for i in enemys[b]:
TypeError: 'enemy' object is not iterable
```

```py
    for b in range(len(enemys)):
        for i in enemys[b]:
            if i != enemys[i][0] and i != enemys[i][1]:
                i.draw(window)
```

этот код должен проверить есть ли одинаковые элементы в списке и если их нету выводить результат, но выводит `'enemy' object is not iterable`.

Comment: На какую точно строку ругается? Приведите **полный** текст ошибки. Ругаться может на какое угодно место, а там точно написано.

Comment: Дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1475454/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я понял, элемент из списка enemys выглядит так: (enemy_x, enemy_y), если это так, то python не может выполнить этот код, так как enemys[b] это координаты, а не список

Comment: а как это исправить?

Comment: полный текст ошибки: line 40, in painter
    for i in enemys[b]:
TypeError: 'enemy' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот код:

```
for i in enemys:
    for j in enemys:
        if i != j:
            i.draw(window)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]