# Проблема с списком в игре

Tags: python, pygame

У меня есть список `enemys` в котором `enemys[0][0]` = `enemys_x`, а `enemys[0][1]` = `enemy_y` список выглядит так: `[[enemy_x, enemy_y, enemy_size, enemy_size, color]]`. Полная ошибка:

```
line 40, in painter for i in enemys[b]: TypeError: 'enemy' object is not iterable
```

Код:

```py
for b in range(len(enemys)):
    for i in enemys[b]:
        if i != enemys[i][0] and i != enemys[i][1]:
            i.draw(window)
```

Этот код должен проверить есть ли одинаковые элементы в списке и если их нету выводить результат но выводит `enemy object is not iterable`

Comment: if i != enemys[b][0] and i != enemys[b][1]:

Comment: @СергейКох ошибка возникает в другой строке и как раз и говорит о том, что ``i`` получить невозможно

Comment: вам смысл ошибки понятен? Что такое ``enemy``?

Comment: судя по всему, список выглядит не так, как написано в вопросе

Comment: @Эникейщик Да у него полная путаница, я просто показал, что I не может быть индексом, так как в нем значения переменных из списка.